# how to start AlarmActvity automaticlly in sepecific time

Tags: java, android

I have Data Base Contain 7 Days Table Hours for Ex:
Friday : 8 AM , 10 Am , 12 PM , 14 Pm .
Monday  : 7 Am , 9 AM .....

And so on .

Now I want to make my Activity Alarm rise On from Sleep on those specific time Automatically .

I want to create day by day alarms Automatically for the same activity . 
But after the last alarm in this day should remove all alarms .

my code :

```
  Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
  cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

  Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
   cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
   cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
   cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 54);
   cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
   cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
   cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));

    //Create a new PendingIntent and add it to the AlarmManager
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
     12345, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
     AlarmManager am =
     (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
     am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
      pendingIntent);
         }
```